# Moving/keeping player on the surface of slope: Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Before explaining my issue first, here is my code:

```
class CollisionTestScene:SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{
    var circle:SKShapeNode?
    var ground:SKShapeNode?
    var move = false

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        ground = SKShapeNode()
        let pathToDraw = CGMutablePath()
        pathToDraw.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: frame.midY - 50))
        pathToDraw.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.maxX, y: frame.midY))
        ground?.path = pathToDraw
        ground?.strokeColor = SKColor.red
        ground?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFrom: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: frame.midY - 50), to: CGPoint(x: frame.maxX, y: frame.midY))
        ground?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ground?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        addChild(ground!)

        circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
        circle?.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY);
        circle?.strokeColor = SKColor.clear
        circle?.fillColor = SKColor.orange
        circle?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
        circle?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        circle?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        circle?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ground!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask
        addChild(circle!)

    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        circle?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        move = true
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        move = false
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        move = false
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if move{
            ground?.position = CGPoint(x: (ground?.position.x)! - 1, y: (ground?.position.y)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Mechanic of the sample is side scroller. When player touches the screen the ground which is incline slope in this example moves towards left. My player remain at given position.

Now initially when my player, circle in this case falls down due to gravity, I make my player static on collision detection handler because by default in given physical world it was rolling back downhill along the slope. This is my first requirement that player never moves back. The ground moves back giving impression that player is moving forward and this will be long side scroller. I may be doing this wrong as I am still figuring out the physics of spritekit.

Second issue is when player touches screen and ground starts moving back the position of player never updates where I want player to be always on surface of ground slope. This is happening ofcourse because my player circle has become static entity.

This is my predicament. If I make my player dynamic then it rolls down the slope which I don't want to. If I make player static I am not able to figure it out how to keep player on surface of slope always. I cannot apply impulse or any force to my player because I do not want to move my player but move ground only.

EDIT 2:
Based on RonMyschuk's comment I adjusted the x value of gravity

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity.dx = 1.36
```

And if you run my code with above new line to update gravity and comment out the collision detection method where I am turning my player to static entity then you will see that I get desired result when I press the screen to move ground.
Only problem with above is that my ground slopes will be coming in various angles like in procedural generator. I will need some formula to calculate and change gravity for different incoming grounds. And there might be some issue where switching gravity isn't fast enough to avoid movement of my player itself. In last case scenario I can have some fixed n ways of various static slopes that will be generated in ground generator and just use static x values of gravity for every different pre-determined slopes.

I would definitely want to know if anyone has a way to keep player on the moving slope for any dynamic angle without moving player itself.

Can please anyone throw insight on how I can keep my player on surface of slope while sloped ground is moving?

**SOLUTION:**
Based on comment by Knight0fDragon, I changed friction of my player and turned off the angular forces. Works well so far by procedurally generated slopes.

```
circle?.physicsBody?.friction = 1.0;
circle?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false;
```

Comment: When you're trying to have a view track the player, the most natural thing in SpriteKit is probably to use a camera node.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skcameranode

Comment: @bg2b Thanks for response but that is not the solution to my problem. My problem is regarding physics on how to keep player on surface of slope.

Comment: have you considered adjusting the x value of your gravity? you could have the appearance of the slope but for all intents it would be a flat plain

Comment: @RonMyschuk Thanks. Yeah adjusting x value for certain angle of slope works. In my above example self.physicsWorld.gravity.dx = 1.36 works if you run the code with that gravity and comment out collision detection method. But in practical level of side scroller the slopes will be come in various angles. The x-value working for certain angle of slope will not work for other slope for example forward down slope. Then I will need some formula to calculate x-gravity for any given angle of incline.

Comment: The point of a camera would be to let the player move according to the physics engine and but have the player followed by the camera so that it appears he's not moving.  So once you can get the physics working correctly with the ground stationary and the player moving, the effect of having the ground moving left instead of the player moving right is accomplished entirely via the camera.

Comment: @bg2b Thanks. If my physics works then it's just a efficiency choice between using camera or scrolling nodes. My problem is again physics where player rolls behind down the slope or forward. What I want is for player to be static on the surface of slope when there is no camera movement or player movement or ground movement. Based on RonMyschuk it can be kept static by adjusting different gravity for different slopes but its again pre-determined value. My main problem is keeping player on surface not about the view. View problem can be done in ways and your suggested camera is one of them.

Comment: @bg2b I haven't mentioned in my post but My level will be infinite scroller based on procedural generation which is all worked out. These grounds are being generated dynamically as player is moving so Camera won't be that good idea here because I don't have pre-defined long level with hand crafted objects placed. All my ground and obstacles will be generating on fly when player is moving forward. Thanks.

Comment: How does a car stay on a hill? Friction and brakes.  Increase your friction and turn off angular rotation.  Once you turn circle dynamic off, he is no longer a major part of the physics works, so of course he will not change.  Do not set this off unless he is indeed static.

Comment: To pin the player to whatever slope, I'd suggest forgetting about trying to use the physics engine at all, since you're going to be fighting it.  Just move the ground (or the player + camera) and force the player's position to be always touching it.  That's a geometry problem.  If the player has radius r and is at position x=0, and a segment of ground at x=0 has y=h, and the ground has makes angle theta with the horizontal, then the player's y should be h+abs(r/cos(theta)) if I didn't calculate incorrectly.  When the ground changes slope, compute the y from each and take the maximum.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Try hiker or backpacker hiking uphill or downhill who can stay still on slope. It will not be very steep slope.

Comment: @bg2b Thanks. I will try this and update you. I was also thinking to use plain trigonometry based approach too. I will try this too. But I was looking for physics based too if there was solution to it as it will make things easier for my other aspects of mechanics.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks it works. Why i never thought of it, silly me.

Comment: Dont ever be afraid to ask yourself how things work in real life.  The physics world is designed to emulate real life